# Simple use of ofxVectorMath

Tags: openframeworks

Been trying to get the relative angle of two vectors.

However what the code outputs is way off.

Anyone know where im going wrong?

Using two vectors and this line

```
ofDrawBitmapString(ofToString(point.angle(mouse), 5), 20, 40);
```

Output should be in degrees as in vec2f states.
Furthermore if you set the two vectors at the same angle but  further apart it gives a different value again.

... confused ?

Anyone used it with any success?

I tried creating my own calcs but using set tan and atan don't even correctly work for me..

What should be a very simple calculation has me stumped.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to get the angle of the mouse relative to the center, using atan2 should get you sorted:

```
ofDrawBitmapString("mouse angle: " + ofToString(ofRadToDeg(atan2(mouseY,mouseX)), 3),30,30);
```

if you want the rotation compared to another point, don't forget to do the subtraction between the two points(e.g. mouse,other point) first.

If you want to get the angle between 2 vectors in 3D(**ofxVec3f**) you need to normalize the two vectors then get the acos of the dot product between the vectors

```
angle_in_radians = acos(v1.dot(v2))
```

**ofxVec3f** already gives you this functionality though the **angle()** and **angleRad()** methods where the angle returns the angle in degrees and angleRad in radians.

Here's a basic test, displaying the angle between two random vectors in the console:

```
ofxVec3f v1(ofRandom(0,20),ofRandom(0,20),ofRandom(0,20));
ofxVec3f v2(ofRandom(0,20),ofRandom(0,20),ofRandom(0,20));

printf("v1(%f,%f,%f)\tv2(%f%f%f)\tangle:%f",v1.x,v1.y,v1.z,v2.x,v2.y,v2.z,v1.angle(v2));
//here's a test print: v1(10.333943,16.629400,5.899722) v2(3.60652910.2126262.595955)   angle:12.418082
```

Comment: Thanks heaps. Didn't quite need the 3d vector implementation as of yet but thanks for the informative reply! Finally using atan2 effectively.

Comment: @aKiwi I'm glad the atan2 works for you. Regarding the 3D vector, it's a bit of vector maths. I found a more detailed explanation here: http://www.euclideanspace.com/maths/algebra/vectors/angleBetween/index.htm , but in any context that discuses vector math, you will get to a part that discuses dot product (and how to calculate the angle between two vectors) and the cross product (and how to calculate the perpendicular between 2 vectors)...As I mentioned in the answer, if you're not interested in the math...just use v1.angle(v2) where v1,v2 are ofxVec3f and you'll get the angle in degrees.